# control physical scan button in PDA

Tags: java, android, button, barcode-scanner

Is it possible to configure the physical scan button of a Android PDA Handheld Terminal and set as a default behavior when every time I scan a QR code after processing the information scanned with java, gets as an example XXX YYYY and it is pasted in wherever app is open like an entry text field.

I have seen that with "public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)" and "e.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN" seems that it is possible to capture the physical PDA button.

Many thanks for any feedback.

I did process all the info and able to get what I want, but need to configure the scan PDA button

It is for Android 12

Comment: Contact the hardware manufacturer.

Comment: I am afraid I got it in China, 80 % cheaper with the idea of testing.

Comment: any others ideas?